# xparse - \NewDocumentCommand definition behaves different if defined in preamble

Tags: errors, xparse

I encountered a very strange behavior for the `\NewDocumentCommand` command in the `xparse` package related to the point of definition. The following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{m >{\SplitList {;}}r<>}{
 #1, #2
}
\Test{1}<123;32>
\end{document}
```

However, if we change the `Test` definition to the preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{m >{\SplitList {;}}r<>}{
 #1, #2
}    

\begin{document}
\Test{1}<123;32>
\end{document}
```

It fails with the following error

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

!
! LaTeX error: "xparse/missing-required"
! 
! Failed to find required argument starting with '<' for command '\Test '.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.44 \Test{1}<
              123;32>
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| The current command '\Test ' expects an argument starting with '<'. LaTeX
| did not find it, and will insert a default value to be processed.
|...............................................
```

This seems pretty weird and unexpected. This was tested on https://www.overleaf.com

Comment: Can't replicate it. Both code examples work.

Comment: Actually tested on a new project and can't replicate either. Very strange...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can't be replicated.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem either. The symptoms suggest that something (probably a package) changes the catcode of `<` or `>` in `\begin{document}`. If you can reproduce this problem in a larger document I suggest you try to find the offending package with a binary search (i.e. remove the lower half of loaded packages, check if the issue persists; if not, delete the upper half and copy the lower half back in; repeat until you have isolated the package). Normally `babel` is a good candidate for catcode changes, but I'm not sure if it ever does `<` or `>`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The error shows a problem in line 44. Your document has much fewer lines, hinting that the error occurs in a document where other stuff happens.

Comment: @egreg founded the solution. I was importing the `babel` package with spanish option which caused the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue can be reproduced only with the Spanish or Galician module for `babel` loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TestPreamble}{m >{\SplitList {;}}r<>}{#1, #2}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TestDocument}{m >{\SplitList {;}}r<>}{#1, #2}

\TestPreamble{1}<123;32>

\TestDocument{1}<123;32>

\end{document}
```

We get

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Failed to find required argument starting with '<' for command
(LaTeX3)        '\TestPreamble '.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.11 \TestPreamble{1}<
                      123;32>
```

The command `\TestDocument` works without problems.

This is due to `<` changing meaning before and after `\begin{document}`. One should always take care of the shorthands defined by the loaded languages when defining personal commands.

The particular issue is solved by using the `es-noquoting` option that disables the (rather useless nowadays) meaning given to `<`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TestPreamble}{m >{\SplitList {;}}r<>}{#1, #2}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TestDocument}{m >{\SplitList {;}}r<>}{#1, #2}

\TestPreamble{1}<123;32>

\TestDocument{1}<123;32>

\end{document}
```